# Is it possible to change color sheme of confirmation dialog of UIApplication.shared.open("tel://XXXXXX")?

Tags: ios, swift

App uses dark and light mode. the application theme may differ from the system theme.

But when I call `UIApplication.shared.open("tel://XXXXXX")` then shows up confiramtion dialog with system theme.

App changes theme like in the next example.

```swift
UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.forEach { scene in
            (scene as? UIWindowScene)?.windows.forEach { window in
                window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark // or .light
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app's dark/light modes should match the system theme- Apple doesn't allow you to override system dialog theme with one that differs from the currently displayed window's user interface style.. This is impossible.